# angularjs uib-timepicker is converting date to UTC

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an AngularJs app and i'm trying to use uib-timepicker. I created a test date in my controller:

```
$scope.testdate = new Date("2000-01-01T09:00:00.000Z");
```

and in my HTML I have:

```
TESTDATE: {{testdate}}
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="testdate"></div>
```

The TESTDATE: is displayed as "2000-01-01T09:00:00.000Z", which is what I expect, but the the timepicker is showing 8:00pm. I'm assuming this is because of my UTC offset. Why is the timepicker changing the time and not using the system timezone? How can I get the 09:00am time to appear in the timepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `Z` ([time zone designator](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)) form your json/string date it will work.

**JS:**

```
$scope.testdate = new Date("2000-01-01T09:00:00.000");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="testdate"></div>
```

Check the [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/THce1c?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can display date in your timezone like below:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

where Arguments like below:
[image: Arguments]

For more information you visit link [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: The time in uib-timepicker is showing incorrectly, not the output line above it.

Comment: Have you tried like this one?
ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}"

Comment: ng-model-options doesn't seem to work. Timezone should be the users local

Comment: Can you write your code here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tfVq3NLgjcuEIg3Nx96P?p=preview